# Show a field only once if the value is the same

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a content-type with a field "Shooting Date" of type "date".

I have a block-view which collects all nodes of this type.

I sort these nodes by "Shooting Date".

I now want to display the year at the top, then all elements in this year.

E.g.:

2017

-Node 1

-Node 2

-Node 3

2016

-Node 4

What I have by default ist:

2017
-Node 1

2017

-Node 2

2017

-Node 3

2016

-Node 4

Can anyone tell me how I can show the year only once if the value is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the "Grouping field".

- Add your date field to your views.
- Click the "Format Settings"

[image]

- Select your date field in "Group Field".

[image]

- Tick the "Use rendered output to group rows".
- Tick the "Remove tags from rendered output".
- Change the date format to "Y".

[image]

- Save.

Comment: Holy cow, that's what I call a perfect answer. Thanks, is works perfectly. One little thing though: It now renders the year as wished but also the year field itself, so one has to hide it in its own settings. :) Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yay. Happy to help :)